# Three JS code won't work despite being a copy

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm following a tutorial and despite the video having a black screen, showing that it's working, I only get a blank white screen. My entire code is a carbon copy and I don't know what's wrong. Any help would be great.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Three JS test</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

All of your code looks correct, but this is just the bootstrapping code that creates the scene, camera, and renderer.  You're never actually telling the renderer to go ahead and do its thing.

Add the following at the end of your code.

```
animate();

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
} // end animate
```

Also see [this page](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene) in the "Getting Started" documentation, under the heading "Rendering the scene":

> *If you copied the code from above into the HTML file we created earlier, you wouldn't be able to see anything. This is because we're not actually rendering anything yet. For that, we need what's called a render or animate loop.*